Why there is difference between Nominatim library and API when reverse geocoding?
I'm trying to use the Nominatim Python library for reverse geocoding, I see that the format is less precise than the output of the HTTP result, I use the following code:
lon = -123.148978
lat = 45.198726
coord = (lon, lat)  # Pass coordinates as a tuple (lon, lat)
result =  await api.reverse(coord)  # Perform reverse geocoding with the tuple

to get the following result:
{'tiger:county': 'Yamhill, OR'}

whereas on the API I get the following result:
{'road': 'Southeast Three Mile Lane',
 'town': 'McMinnville',
 'county': 'Yamhill County',
 'state': 'Oregon',
 'ISO3166-2-lvl4': 'US-OR',
 'postcode': '97128',
 'country': 'United States',
 'country_code': 'us'}

I am new to the tool. Do you have any idea how to use it or where I can find detailed documentation on how to use these functions?

To get more details when reverse geocoding try to include the address_details=True argument in the parameters which by default is set to False:
result =  await api.reverse(coord, address_details=True)

Keep in mind, that order matters, see "Reverse Geocoding" for more details:

Reverse geocoding generates an address from a coordinate given as
latitude and longitude.

Otherwise, one of the following errors could arise:

ValueError: Latitude must be in the [-90; 90] range.


or

"Unable to geocode"


